# Stored Procedure SQL Injection

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, stored-procedures, webforms

I'm trying to prevent SQL Injection with my stored procedure and get the values by C# or ASP.NET Web Forms. This is the code where the code starts

```
 public DataTable getDataTable(string sSQL, List<OleDbParameter> param, string sConnectionString)
 { return getOledbDataTable(sSQL, param, sConnectionString); }

 public DataTable getOledbDataTable(string sSQL, List<OleDbParameter> param ,string sConnectionString)
 {
    OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection();
    OleDbCommand oCmd = new OleDbCommand();
    OleDbDataAdapter oDA = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    DataTable oDataTable = new DataTable();

    oCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cn.ConnectionString = sConnectionString;
    cn.Open();
    oCmd.CommandText = sSQL;
    oCmd.Parameters.AddRange(param.ToArray());
    oCmd.Connection = cn;
    oDA.SelectCommand = oCmd;
    oDA.Fill(oDataTable);
    cn.Close();

    return oDataTable;
 }
```

Then when I want to query/save a data, this is where the function call and this kind of method works and prevents SQL injection: NOTE(This is just a sample 1 code snippet verifying if the user is admin or not)

```
 public DataTable User(string sUser)
 {
    List<OleDbParameter> param = new List<OleDbParameter>();
    param.Add(new OleDbParameter("@USER", sUser));

    return mda.getDataTable("[SECURITY].upSelectUser", param, MyDataAccess.sCollateralMgrConnectionString);
 }
```

This is the old code before i implement the code above:

```
 public DataTable User(string sUser)
 {
     return mda.getDataTable("[SECURITY].upSelectUser '" + sUser + "'", MyDataAccess.sCollateralMgrConnectionString);
 }
```

**So my mainly question is**, if I have ternary operator or this kind of code. How do implement this by using the Collection List?

```
 public DataTable AllCollateral(MySecurity oMySec, string sStatus)
 {
    return mda.getDataTable("[DBO].[upSelectAllCollateral]" + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sStatus) ? string.Empty : " '" + sStatus + "', '" + oMySec.Userid + "' 1"), MyDataAccess.sCollateralMgrConnectionString);
 }
```

And this is the snippet for stored procedure under [DBO].[upSelectAllCollateral]

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[upSelectAllCollateral]
   @Status varchar(255) = NULL,
   @USERID varchar(8)
 AS
   .....
```

For the SQL Injection error. I run my application in Veracode.

This is what I tried and nothing works/wont get the data I wanted.

```
 public DataTable AllCollateral(MySecurity oMySec, string sStatus)
 {
     List<OleDbParameter> param = new List<OleDbParameter>();
     param.Add(new OleDbParameter("@USERID", oMySec.Userid));    
     param.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Status", sStatus));

     return mda.getDataTable("[DBO].[upSelectAllCollateral]"), param, MyDataAccess.sCollateralMgrConnectionString);
 }

 public DataTable AllCollateral(MySecurity oMySec, string sStatus)
 {
     List<OleDbParameter> param = new List<OleDbParameter>();
     param.Add(new OleDbParameter("@USERID", oMySec.Userid));    
     param.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Status", sStatus));

     return mda.getDataTable("[DBO].[upSelectAllCollateral] " + (string.IsNullOrEmpty("@USERID") ? string.Empty : " @Status, @USERID 1"), param, MyDataAccess.sCollateralMgrConnectionString);
 }
```

Comment: You prevent SQL injection by using parametrized queries (even dynamic parametized queries did right will prevent issues). Using SPs is in general a good way to reuse a parametrized query unless you are just building your string in the DB side and callign an `EXECUTE`. That said a good option to pass a list or even a data set and use a join with this. But it depends on the DBMS, in MS SQL Server for example there are the .net `SqlDbType.Structured` to pass a Table type to a SP

Comment: What is the value of `oMySec.Userid`? Of `sStatus`? If you run a SQL Trace on the database what command is being sent to it? Why are the two parameters listed in the wrong order?